# Full Calendar - Scheduler external event set fixed start time and end time

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have create an external event panel to allow the user to drag the event to the full calendar - scheduler view. But I want the draggable event to be fixed start time and end time when user has release the event on the calendar. How can I do that? I've tried to .each every event and provide the start time for it.

My code:

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                start: "09:00",
                time: "09:00",
                durationEditable: false,
                duration: "09:00"
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag

            });

        });
```

Comment: are you comfortable in using angular js?

Comment: My working environment do not allow me to use angular.js

Comment: i don't think "time" and "duration" are valid properties of a FullCalendar event. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ - I think you need to define the "end" property. FullCalendar allows you to define custom properties if you need them for your own purposes, but it will ignore them.

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved?

Comment: Yes I did managed to resolve the problem. I tried to clone the event object and set its start end time, then I remove the event in the event receive function and render the modified event